# Why does my AWS lb target group stay in a "draining" state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate, amazon-elb

I'm trying to deploy a docker image via terraform and AWS ECS using Fargate. Using terraform, I've created a VPC, two private and two public subnets, a ECR repository to store the image, an ECS cluster, ECS task, ECS service, and a load balancer with a target group.

These resources are created successfully, but the target group is constantly:

1. varying in the number of targets that are shown. For instance, refreshing will sometimes show 3 registered targets. Sometimes it will show 4.
2. Usually have a status of "draining" and details that say "Target deregistration in progress". Sometimes one of them will have a status of "initial" and details that say "Target registration in progress"

Additionally, visiting the URL of the load balancer returns a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813074/docker-instance-running-on-private-subnet-aws-fargate), that led to me [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/task-networking-in-aws-fargate/), which helped me better understand how Fargate works but I'm having trouble translating this into the terraform + aws method I'm trying to implement.

I'm suspecting the issue could be in how the security groups are allowing/disallowing traffic but I'm still a novice with dev ops stuff so I appreciate in advance any help offered.

Here is the terraform `main.tf` that I've used to create the resources. Most of it is gathered from different tutorials and adjusted with updates whenever terraform screamed at me about a deprecation.

So, which parts of the following configuration is wrong and is causing the target groups to constantly be in a draining state?

Again, thanks in advance for any help or insights provided!

```
# ..terraform/main.tf

# START CREATE VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  instance_tenancy= "default"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_classiclink = false

  tags = {
    Name = "vpc"
  }
}
# END CREATE VPC



# START CREATE PRIVATE AND PUBLIC SUBNETS
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "public-subnet-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"

  tags = {
    Name = "public-subnet-2"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.3.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  availability_zone = "us-east-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "private-subnet-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.4.0/24"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  availability_zone = "us-east-1b"

  tags = {
    Name = "private-subnet-1"
  }
}
# END CREATE PRIVATE AND PUBLIC SUBNETS



# START CREATE GATEWAY
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "vpc_gateway" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  tags = {
    Name = "vpc-gateway"
  }
}
# END CREATE GATEWAY



# START CREATE ROUTE TABLE AND ASSOCIATIONS
resource "aws_route_table" "public_route_table" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.vpc_gateway.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "public-route-table"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "route_table_association_1" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route_table.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "route_table_association_2" {
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public_route_table.id
}
# END CREATE ROUTE TABLE AND ASSOCIATIONS



# START CREATE ECR REPOSITORY
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "api_ecr_repository" {
 name = "api-ecr-repository"
}
# END CREATE ECR REPOSITORY



# START CREATE ECS CLUSTER
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "api_cluster" {
  name = "api-cluster"
}
# END CREATE ECS CLUSTER



# START CREATE ECS TASK AND DESIGNATE 'FARGATE'
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "api_cluster_task" {
  family = "api-cluster-task"
  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "name": "api-cluster-task",
      "image": "${aws_ecr_repository.api_ecr_repository.repository_url}",
      "essential": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 4000,
          "hostPort": 4000
        }
      ],
      "memory": 512,
      "cpu": 256
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  memory                   = 512
  cpu                      = 256
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
}
# END CREATE ECS TASK AND DESIGNATE 'FARGATE'



# START CREATE TASK POLICIES
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
      }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name               = "ecs-take-execution-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_execution_role_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
# END CREATE TASK POLICIES



# START CREATE ECS SERVICE
resource "aws_ecs_service" "api_cluster_service" {
  name = "api-cluster-service"
  cluster = aws_ecs_cluster.api_cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.api_cluster_task.arn
  launch_type = "FARGATE"
  desired_count = 1

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.api_lb_target_group.arn
    container_name = aws_ecs_task_definition.api_cluster_task.family
    container_port = 4000
  }

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.ecs_tasks.id]
    subnets = [
      aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id,
      aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
    ]
    assign_public_ip = true
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb_listener.api_lb_listener, aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ecs_task_execution_role_attachment]
}


resource "aws_security_group" "api_cluster_security_group" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = -1
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
# END CREATE ECS SERVICE



# CREATE LOAD BALANCER
resource "aws_alb" "api_load_balancer" {
  name = "api-load-balancer"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets = [
    aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id,
    aws_subnet.public_subnet_2.id
  ]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer_security_group" {
  name = "allow-load-balancer-traffic"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  ingress {
    from_port = 80
    to_port = 80
    protocol = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"] 
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
# END CREATE LOAD BALANCER



# CREATE ECS TASK SECURITY GROUP
resource "aws_security_group" "ecs_tasks" {
  name        = "ecs-tasks-sg"
  description = "allow inbound access from the ALB only"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    protocol        = "tcp"
    from_port       = 4000
    to_port         = 4000
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.load_balancer_security_group.id]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
# END ECS TASK SECURITY GROUP



# START CREATE LOAD BALANCER TARGET GROUP
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "api_lb_target_group" {
  name = "api-lb-target-group"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold= "3"
    interval = "90"
    protocol = "HTTP"
    matcher = "200-299"
    timeout = "20"
    path = "/"
    unhealthy_threshold = "2"
  }
}
# END CREATE LOAD BALANCER TARGET GROUP



# START CREATE LOAD BALANCER LISTENER
resource "aws_lb_listener" "api_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.api_load_balancer.arn
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.api_lb_target_group.arn
  }
}
# END CREATE LOAD BALANCER LISTENER
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are not using `api_cluster_security_group` at all in your setup, thus its not clear what it is its purpose. Also in your `aws_security_group.ecs_tasks` you are allowing only port `4000`. However, due to d**ynamic port mapping** between ALB and ECS services, you should **allow all ports**, not only `4000`.

There could be other issues, which are not apparent yet.

Comment: Ahh. The `api_cluster_security_group` was originally the value I set for the `security_group` of the `api_cluster_service`. Was trying things out and forgot to reset it to that. I've dropped the `ecs_tasks` for the `api_cluster_security_group`, which has all ports set to 0 (allow all). Still having the same issue. Thank for point those issues out though!

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship Do your ecs service work without ALB? Can you access it directly?

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship Everything else seems to be fine. Maybe your docker image does not work. Sadly, I don't know what kind of application you are running.

Comment: hmm. So I was following [these directions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance-connect.html) and I don't even see an instance when I select the created cluster. The cluster is active and shows 1 pending tasks count and 1 active service count. But I see nothing when I click the "ECS Instances" in the AWS UI.

Comment: And I'm running a rails 6 API application. I can docker-compose up locally and the applications works

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship You are using fargate, which doesn't have any instances.

Comment: Oo duh... Is [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/) really the suggested way to handle this on AWS? ai yai yai

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship I'm not sure how does it relate to your issue? You want to "ssh" into your container?

Comment: You asked if I can access it directly. Is there another way I can test that aside from SSH'ing into it?

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship I mean does your api work if you access it without ALB, e.g. `curl <task_ip>:4000`? Are you certian your containers work correctly?

Comment: Nah. I've tried to curl every <ip>:4000 in my target group. They all hang and then "operation timed out"

Comment: @wheresmyspaceship This seems as SG issue and `api_cluster_security_group` is correct. I would go a step back. Just try to launch your contain in a basic ECS fargate task. No custom VPC, no ALB. Just plain task in a default public VPC to verify if it even works in the most simplest scenario. Inspect its SG in AWS console.